# Task configuration for "make clean" doesn't work in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c, visual-studio, makefile

I wrote this simple program:

**main.c:**

```
#include "main.h"

void nothing(){}

int main(){
  nothing();  
  return 0;
}
```

**main.h:**

```
void nothing();
```

Till now compiled and ran it using this generic `Makefile`:

```
CC = gcc
CC_FLAGS = -g
EXEC = run
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.c=.o)

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) -o $(EXEC)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CC_FLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)
```

Now I want to compile and run it with VS, but the compilation and cleaning (by `make clean`) must be performed by the makefile. So I opened the folder of the program (contains all 3 files) in VS, and configure the following tasks for it at `tasks.vs.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "taskName": "BUILD",
      "appliesTo": "/",
      "workingDirectory": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "command": "make",
      "type": "default"
    },
    {
      "taskName": "CLEAN",
      "appliesTo": "/",
      "workingDirectory": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "command": "make clean",
      "type": "default"
    }
  ]
}
```

The task for `BUILD` works, but for `CLEAN` I get:

```
'"make clean"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,      
operable program or batch file.
```

Do you know how can I fix my task for `CLEAN` , so that it will perform make clean like I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string given as the value for `"command"` is interpreted as a single command. To send arguments to your command, like `clean`, the schema provides the possibility to give an array of arguments. In your case, it would look like this:

```
      "command": "make",
      "args": [ "clean" ],
```